# d3JS: Transitions between valuelines of different points counts

Tags: javascript, d3.js

There have been similar questions before, but I have not found an altogether clear answer for this:

Say I have a basic line graph composed of **valuelineA** with 20 vertices.

I want to transition this line to another **valuelineB** with 256 vertices.

The X Domain remains the same, as does the Y Domain.  Assume that **valuelineA** and **valuelineB** are evenly distributed across the X domain (time).

How would I get the transition to occur between **valuelineA** and **valuelineB** such that there is no horizontal animation?

The code below will transition between **valuelineA** and **valuelineB**, but the transitions squeezes **valuelineA** into the first 20 vertices of **valuelineB**.

```
 var trends=svg.append("path")      
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valuelineA(dataA));

 trends
        .transition()
        .duration(3200)
        .attr("d", valuelineB(dataB))
    ;
```

I've found a few posts which are similar ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588134/extending-paths-in-d3-with-transition) and [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3916621)), but it's still not entirely clear to me how to perform what seems like a basic operation.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an easy solution, I'm afraid.  Here are some pointers on how to go about it:

For background: the default transition finds all the numbers in the string created by the new valueline function, and matches them up with numbers in the "d" attribute string currently attached to the path element.  Numbers that have a match get transitioned, but all the extra points at the end of the line just get tacked on.

You can write a custom transition function to have more control (look up "d3 custom tween" for examples), but that still leaves the problem of how to figure out which points to transition and which to insert in between -- and *where* to insert the new points.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20939701/3128209) I created a function to interpolate values for new points which you might want to look at. Note that in that question the number of data points wasn't changing (some were just going from undefined to defined).  That meant the first half of the problem -- matching up the old and new data points -- was easy.

As a solution to wonky transitions, I proposed actually breaking the path up into individual line segments so you could add each one in in place.  That actually would solve the matching problem too, since you could use a [data-join key function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data) to do the matching (if you want to check out the code that is used internally to do that, it's at [lines 32 to 64 of data.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/c247e1626118de41b3d40e2a711354f76e004343/src/selection/data.js)).

The many-lines approach might be a solution you could adapt.  Otherwise, if you want to stick with using a single `<path>` element for the linegraph (which has definite performance benefits if you've got thousands of data points, you're going to need to create a path for the start of your transition that has the same number of points as your final line.

Here's your plan of attack:

1. Create a transition data array that includes a data point for every x value in your *new* data array (I'm assuming all the old x-values will also be included in the larger dataset, if not it gets trickier).
2. For each x-value, set its y-value to be the value from the old data if it exists, or an interpolated value otherwise.
3. Update the path's "d" value *without a transition* to be a line based on this new data array.  If you did everything right it shouldn't look like anything has changed, because all the new data points will be exactly on the lines between the old data points.
4. Now, create the transition to the line for your new data; the transition will be smooth because every new point has a matching starting point.

As I said above, you could do this all within a custom "tween" function, but that's probably just adding extra complication.